# How to prevent my website form doing a toLocaleString to a decimal number?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Right now my Vue 2 web app does this weird thing where it converts a number for example a '1.324' to a '1,324' if localization is switched to France, or I translate the website to French.

Is there a way to prevent this type of change, and not let the '.' become a ',' in any cases?

I'm not using the

> .toLocaleString()

Comment: You could use `.toLocaleString("en-US")` to make it use a dot for the decimal separator.

Comment: Sorry, I gave that a try but it does not work as intended

Comment: What went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: It would be nice if we could see the offending code...